# IIS 6 Application Pool inconsistently is disabled Automatically

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a MVC Web Application deployed to a 2003 Server running IIS 6. There is an inconsistent behavior that started this week when we created a new Domain service account with God rights to be used as the identity for the Application Pool and the Anonymous User for the Website with Integrated Authentication set. This Service account has also been added to the SQL users with full rights to the data.

The inconsistent behavior is that the Web Application will run fine, hitting the data, etc..., then out of the blue the Application Pool gets automatically disabled. I check the event logs on the server and sure enough I see two warnings and an error saying that the Identity is INVALID and that the pool was disabled.

I turn it back on and then try to browse to the Website again and BOOM! It does it again. We finally after three attempts lock the account out and have to unlock it. Then it spirals back to the same issue.

Any ideas? Because I'm at my wits end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem might be solved because the question is old, but anyway.

Try manual login with username and password, then
reapply the identity on the application pool, answer yes to apply user rights if questioned, restart the application pool and check the eventlog for errors.

Make sure the useraccount has the appropriate user rights , there will be complaints in the eventlog otherwise. Also make sure allow login to on the user account has the server entered or allow any.

Thanks

Andreas